# Динамическое создание EditText

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[Здесь я нашел частичное решение своей проблемы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136060/how-an-edit-text-can-be-created-dynamically-in-android)

Я переделал так, чтобы пользователь вводил размер матрицы и с помощью Button создавалось нужное количество Edittext'ов для ввода матрицы. Допустим, я вывел нужное количество edittext'ов для матрицы и хочу ввести другую матрицу, другого размера. При втором вводе старые edittextы не очищаются, новые прибавляются к ним.

Вопрос:

1. Как убрать старые EditText'ы, чтобы новые не добавлялись к старым, а создавались заново.
2. Какой ID присваивается этим edittext'ам? Можно ли установить свой? Например a11,a12,a21,a22 итд

Answer (score 2):

1. removeView(View v)
2. setId(int id), где id это целое число

Но это все детали. Зачем вам вообще создавать вручную EditText? не проще ли воспользоваться предназначенным для этого компонентом типа GridView?