# Как задать ID динамически созданному View

Tags: java, android

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        EditText a = new EditText(this);
        content.addView(a);
    }
```

У меня есть i-1 динамических Edittext'ов, мне нужно из них получить значения, как мне в таком случае обращаться к ним через

`Double.parseDouble(???)`,

и как дать им id например a1,a2,a3...

Comment: В [прошлый раз](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/434656/177345) что то было непонятно по ID?

Comment: Создаешь класс, наследуешь его от EditText, присваиваешь ему параметр id, делаешь getter и setter. После в цикле выставляешь ему id как i-тое значение.

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего собрать их в массив. Но можно и воспользоваться view.setId(int id). А ещё лучше сгенерировать уникальный id, что бы не было коллизий:

view.setId(View.generateViewId());

Comment: Небольшой проблемой может быть то, что `generateViewId()` - [added in API level 17](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId())

Comment: уникальный id должен быть внутри текущей layout, поэтому setId(1000+i) вполне нормальный вариант :)